# Microsoft SharePoint 2010: upload multiple documents without Internet Explorer and Microsoft Office

Tags: 2010, file-upload, internet-explorer, mobile, office

A client of us asked if it is possible for them to be able to upload multiple documents while they are on an iPad or Android tablet. It is possible to upload one document at a time, but because Microsoft Office and Internet Explorer (with the ActiveX element "STSUpld.UploadCtl") should be available, this function is not available on tablets.

Are there any cross browser third party plugins (either free or paid) I can install so that this will be possible? I searched a lot, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used the RadAsyncUpload control from Telerik in SharePoint 2013. You shouldn't have problems implementing it on 2010. Demo [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manually-request-crawling-and-reindexing-of-a-site-9afa977d-39de-4321-b4ca-8c7c7e6d264e).

The control will upload multiple files on modern browsers and will fall back to a Silverlight/Flash control on old ones (for example IE 9).

Regarding tablets, this control was tested on Android and iPad and worked on both. But, have in mind that on iPad you can only upload images, and one at a time. This is not the case for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple file uploads require the STSUpld.UploadCtl ActiveX component, which is only supported by Internet Explorer.

There are several (untested) options:

A. Try [RemoteIE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/11/02/announcing-remoteie-test-the-latest-ie-on-windows-mac-os-x-ios-and-android.aspx).

B. Use a remote desktop tool like VNC or RDP to run IE on a Windows computer.

C. Buy a Microsoft tablet.

D. Install Wine and run IE in that.

E. Install VMware, VirtualBox, or VirtualPC, install an OS, and run IE in that.

F. Try the [np-activex](https://code.google.com/p/np-activex/) extension:

> This project enables ActiveX plug-ins for NPAPI browsers. Especially,
>   for Chrome, some automatic inject scripts are provided to load ActiveX
>   plug-in on webpages without any manual operations for trusted sites.

G. Use a [WebDAV File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ddo.shigadroid.webdavfilemanager&hl=en). That works like the "Open in Explorer" feature of SharePoint and is the best alternative to the ActiveX component.